# Xcode line duplication during writing

Tags: xcode6.3

Recently I have installed Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570) I have a problem during writing code.

I don't know, what can I call this but I took a screenshot of it.
[image]

Is it a set up on setting of xcode? I checked TextEditing in Xcode preferences but I don't found anything to fix it.

Comment: That looks like a bug. The first line is not showing correctly.